# Integrating MicroSoft CodePush to Swift Project

Tags: swift, react-native, code-push

I integrated React Native in a swift project. I followed the steps in the following link https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#ios-setup to integrate code push to the project.

As there is no Libraries folder in my project, i created one folder and imported CodePush.xcodeproj to that folder.

Since being a swift project, I added the line #import "CodePush.h" to the bridging header file. But when i try to build my project it says 'CodePush.h file not found' error. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed the issue by following the steps. (Using **Pod**)

1. Install Code Push by running the following command in the terminal from the App's root directory.

   ```
    npm install --save react-native-code-push
   ```
2. Add the CodePush pod to the Podfile.

   ```
    pod 'CodePush', :path => './node_modules/react-native-code-push'
   ```
3. Install the pod.

   ```
    pod install
   ```
4. Add the codepush header file to the BridgingHeader file.
    `#import "CodePush.h"`
5. Now you can access CodePush from the swift file.

   ```
   CodePush.bundleURL()
   ```